# Samsung mobile charging screen blink issue

Tags: charging, boot-loop

While charging I my Samsung J7 mobile via wall charger it's shows charging ICON **Blink**. If try to power on it will always show startup logo (model name) and again turn off display and it's **restart always**.

But when I pressed **`Home+Power+VolumeDown`** It's shown boot window.But it's not blink or restart.That window work perfect and I try to install OS via Odin3 v3.09.But it's not resolve my issue because when device restart It can't update apps because withing 10-15 seconds device restart again.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Battery replaced and now it's working**